# Displaying Inky the ghost from Pac-Man using ANSI escape codes

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

## Challenge

Display Inky the ghost from Pac-Man using only [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

[image: fix_inky]

Here's a text representation of the image

```
B B B B B C C C C B B B B B
B B B C C C C C C C C B B B
B B C C C C C C C C C C B B
B C W W C C C C W W C C C B
B W W W W C C W W W W C C B
B E E W W C C E E W W C C B
C E E W W C C E E W W C C C
C C W W C C C C W W C C C C
C C C C C C C C C C C C C C
C C C C C C C C C C C C C C
C C C C C C C C C C C C C C
C C B C C C B B C C C B C C
C B B B C C B B C C B B B C
```

| Code | ANSI Escape Code | Background Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | "\x1b[40m" | Black |
| C | "\x1b[46m" | Cyan |
| W | "\x1b[47m" | White |
| E | "\x1b[44m" | Blue |

## ANSI Intro

This C [example](https://godbolt.org/z/qhjj96YqG) shows the use of ANSI escape codes to print [image: example]

## Disclaimer

No Inky's were harmed in the making of this challenge. [image: inky_note]

Comment: Suggest an image in text to copy

Comment: Welcome to the site. This site is for recreational programming competition. This question is not yet sufficiently well defined to form a competition. You've added an objective scoring criterion (as mentioned in the box at top right) but the challenge needs more clarity. Are you looking specifically for the ANSI output, or would any code that produces the image suffice? If it has to be the ANSI output, it would be best to give the exact required output in the question. Also, there's no reason to restrict the challenge to C (we do have tips questions, but not for a task as specific as this)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt If you read the bottom, the challenge is not restricted to C, and I think it's clear from the title that OP is asking for the image to be drawn in ANSI escape codes, although you could argue that it still needs clarity there.

Comment: May we output extra black lines at the top and/or the bottom of the ghost?

Comment: Nice idea! How about frame it with black lines around the ghost? Might make the contrast more impactful?

Comment: My point was not to modify the core task, but rather to make it more flexible for golfing purposes. (But it' up to you.)

Comment: Is PETSCII okay, or does it have to be ANSI?

Comment: It would be interesting to see inky displayed on a Commodore 64 (using PETSCII) or emulator. If it works, I see why no reason to restrict inky to just ANSI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 146 bytes

NB: The actual code contains the unprintable character `\x1b`.

```javascript
f=(x=n=0)=>n<195?(x>13?`
`:`\x1b[4${"6074"[[5301,4781,4097,p=2731,p,2861,130,,,,,748,2458][y=n/15|0]*3>>x&1|7800/"52225"[y-3]>>x&2]}m `)+f(++n%15):""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjdCoIwGIDh826hkxgVW67atx@3oq0LGYJiGoVNyQiluvZV78Fz8F6LZ9GX90v3WIf2VMVYWzzYYBmxLhxgp454cCCO@STf51Mv5y@UMi2R90owoFKbH2ynaWe5FkA7yk0KFASj/7Q0lEtlMj/asAX1ZtlKODcs4a0NY1ukOOcK@XEtsv/m2ec2y0lS4yQJC1Bkj1As29C3TbVp2jOuMSHxCw)

Or [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcjdCoIwGIDh826hkxgVW67atx83pc0LGYJRGYVNyQijuvaV78Fz8F73z31/uF@6xzq0x1OMtcWDDZYR68IOsrTAgwNRVJMqr6Zezt8oZVoi75VgQKU2f1imaWe5FkA7yk0KFASjY1oayqUyFEr/smEL6sPKlXBuWMJHG8a2SHHOFfKvtSjHzcvvbVaRpMZJEhagSI5QPLShb5vTpmnPuMaExB8) to restore a black background.

#### Output

[image: Inky]

#### Encoding

| y | black/blue layer | decimal | / 3 | white/blue layer | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11111000011111 | 15903 | 5301 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 1 | 11100000000111 | 14343 | 4781 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 2 | 11000000000011 | 12291 | 4097 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 3 | 10000000000001 | 8193 | 2731 | 00001100001100 | 780 |
| 4 | 10000000000001 | 8193 | 2731 | 00011110011110 | 1950 |
| 5 | 10000110000111 | 8583 | 2861 | 00011110011110 | 1950 |
| 6 | 00000110000110 | 390 | 130 | 00011110011110 | 1950 |
| 7 | 00000000000000 | 0 | 0 | 00001100001100 | 780 |
| 8 | 00000000000000 | 0 | 0 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 9 | 00000000000000 | 0 | 0 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 10 | 00000000000000 | 0 | 0 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 11 | 00100011000100 | 2244 | 748 | 00000000000000 | 0 |
| 12 | 01110011001110 | 7374 | 2458 | 00000000000000 | 0 |

Comment: Pretty, nice work! I wonder instead of using a single character for each rectangular block, maybe make it double the width using two characters so they're more square looking. Just a thought.

Comment: This is code-golf. Nobody is going to do that if it costs an extra byte, unless this is a strict requirement. ;-)

Comment: True. I just tried double spacing myself and the overall size went from 809 to 812, so single character width is fine. Thanks.

Comment: It is not a DOS terminal, it is Command Prompt.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 151 bytes

*-3 thanks to [@vengy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/119544/vengy)*
*-28 thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

Essentially a port of my JS answer.

```c
n;y;main(x){for(;n<195;printf(x>13?"\n":"[4%cm ","6074"[L"㸟㠇〃  ↇƆ\0\0\0\0ࣄ᳎"[y=n++/15]>>x&1|(y>2&y<8)*7800/(~y&3?2:5)>>x&2]))x=n%15;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/PutI6NzEzT6NCszotv0jDOs/G0NLUuqAoM68kTaPCztDYXikmT8lKSTraRDU5V0FJR8nMwNxEKdpH6fGO@Y8XtD9uaH7U0AhCbe3H2mIMIPDB4paHm/uUoitt87S19Q1NY@3sKtQMazQq7YzUKm0sNLXMLQwM9DXqKtWM7Y2sTDVB0kaxmpoVtnmqhqbWtf///0tOy0lML/6vWw4A)

#### Output

[image: Inky]

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 147 bytes

```c
i=182;main(){for(;i--;)printf("\e[4%cm %s","0674"[3&"ATPATQETQUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUeVeVUzWzGe~e~PiZiJTiUiATUUE@TUU@@PU"[i/3]>>i%3*2],i%14?"":"\e[0m\n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3NCoJAFEDhV4kLExoO@UdFQ6YLCVopzBikLmQY5UJaaBAY@ehNtewsvu2RtJFSa9w5G5e1FXaG@ayvvcGQUmbeeuzutQGFyn0i2xkZwAJ7tfYh9@YQ8STiacxT8Z/KVCbG03hQk5oSPOORo8CICxGHX8IwEZDj0iuDAIm3cEsLiePvAba/kd0WHZjspfVb1peqGTR9fAA)

-4B from ceilingcat

Port like

Assumes that after `...TUU@@PU` there are 2 null bytes

Comment: Could shave off another 6 bytes by replacing `\x1b` with the unprintable `ESC` character.

Comment: @vengy Like I said in JavaScript answer, if U+001B is used then the string also can be 4 char per byte

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore C64, using PETSCII graphics, ~392 BASIC bytes

The simplest way to do this is to use the reverse character mode to print out white spaces, but changing the colours as necessary. These are [Control characters](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/control_character) in Commodore BASIC, similar to escaped characters in a C or PHP string. We will use a string array `B$`, and then a `FOR/NEXT` loop to output to the C64 screen. All colours in this listing are accessed by the control (often referred to as `CTRL`) key, by pressing the following key combinations:

```
{BLACK} is CTRL + 1
{WHITE} is CRTL + 2
{CYAN} is CTRL + 4
{BLUE} is CRTL + 7
{REVERSE ON} is CTRL + 9
```

To make the listing clearer and easier to type in, `{SPACE x 5}` indicates 5 spaces following the control character, as looking at the listing in Commodore BASIC might not be very clear.

Here is the listing:

```
0DIMB$(12):B$(.)="{BLACK}{SPACE x 5}{CYAN}{SPACE x 4}{BLACK}{SPACE x 5}":B$(1)="{BLACK}{SPACE x 3}{CYAN}{SPACE x 8}{BLACK}{SPACE x 3}"
1B$(2)="{BLACK}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 10}{BLACK}{SPACE x 2}":B$(3)="{BLACK}{SPACE}{CYAN}{SPACE}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 4}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 3}{BLACK}{SPACE}"
2B$(4)="{BLACK}{SPACE}{WHITE}{SPACE x 4}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{WHITE}{SPACE x 4}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLACK}{SPACE}":B$(5)="{BLACK}{SPACE}{BLUE}{SPACE x 2}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLUE}{SPACE x 2}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLACK}{SPACE}"
3B$(6)="{CYAN}{SPACE}{BLUE}{SPACE x 2}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLUE}{SPACE x 2}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 3}":B$(7)="{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 4}{WHITE}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 4}"
4B$(8)="{CYAN}{SPACE x 14}":B$(9}=B$(8):B$(10)=B$(8):B$(11)="{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLACK}{SPACE}{CYAN}{SPACE x 3}{BLACK}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 3}{BLACK}{SPACE}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}"
5B$(12)="{CYAN}{SPACE}{BLACK}{SPACE x 3}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLACK}{SPACE x 2}{CYAN}{SPACE x 2}{BLACK}{SPACE x 3}{CYAN}{SPACE}":FORI=.TO12:PRINT"{REVERSE ON}"B$(I):NEXT
```

Some notes: be careful when entering line 4 as it is 80 characters in length (the maximum number of characters in a logical C64 line). Cursor up so that the flashing cursor is over one of the characters on the line and press the return key. Or, enter this into a Commodore C128, which allows for 160 characters in a logical line; this will work in C64 or C128 mode. I typed this in again from the listing above to check that the number of spaces and control characters are correct, and it seems fine. Best viewed with `POKE 53280, 0: POKE 53281, 0: RUN`.

By using C128 BASIC, and with the 160 PETSCII character per logical line, this can be crunched further as you will be able to reduce the line numbers. Some bytes could also be saved by removing some of the control characters, for instance, where `B$(0)` ends with `{BLACK}` there is no need to start `B$(1)` with `{BLACK}`. I will try to crunch this further to save some more bytes.

And here is how things look on a C64 (at least a C64 emulator):

[image: Commodore C64 PAC-Man Ghost "Inky"]

[image: Commodore C64 PETSCII PAC-Man Ghost "Inky" BASIC listing]

Comment: Wow! Awesome to see inky on a C64 emulator using PETSCII. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p0513`, 132 bytes

```perl
s!!5.2B8.4B5.5B3.CLBCLB2.2MB2MB2.,MB,MB.@/L@/L2BM2BM24B.B<.B<B<2.B2.B3..!;s/\d+(.)/$1x$&/ge;s/./ord$&/ge;s/.{14}\K/
/g;s/./.[4$&m /g
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#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)

### Explanation

The string of random numbers and symbols is an RLE string that contains the data for all the background colours (only the last digit, as the first digit's always `4`), this is stored in `$_` via the `s///`ubstitution operator. This is decoded to repeated runs of characters and each of those characters is replaced with its `ord`inal value, split into run of `14` characters and has the ANSI escape code string wrapped around each value.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 150 bytes

```javascript
f=(x=182)=>x?`\x1B[4${'0674'[3&Buffer('ATPATQETQUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUeVeVUzWzGe~e~PiZiJTiUiATUUE@TUU@@PU')[--x/3|0]>>x%3*2]}m `+(x%14?'':`\x1b[0m
`)+f(x):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1NC4IwAIDhu7@iQ7YtsTSlwtBUkKCTwVaQCfaxxUIzsmJY@ddXHXsPz/U9bR/ban/ll5t@Lg9USuZC4ZrjAXI9Mc02wgwTu/0ExnBkg8TqhHfG6BWCAMcBXkR4Qf6jS7ok9aqe0YY2MV/zOeaEB5iQyP/i@zEBKNF10bdeRup5QrW6g/RdtDINCtW0pwA4v@suMQolQxqDAjkAyImyL89VmdNeXh4hgwjJDw)

Hardcode

Arnauld's solution spill color and mine don't. Removing this difference mine is shorter, but Arnauld usen't Buffer

I don't use char `\x1B` since otherwise it's better encode 4 pos in a char

Comment: Tested on linux and Inky looks good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc, msvc), 228 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
j,i[]={89391445,88080405,83886085,77597185,111684225,132660865,65552000,10488320,0,0,0,4214800,22040660};main(){for(;j<182;j++)printf("\x1B[4%cm%s","6074"[(i[j/14]>>(2*(13-j%14)))&3],j%14==13?" \x1b[0m\n":" ");}
```

NB: The actual code contains the unprintable `ESC` character `\x1b`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/6751ejE5K)

## Output

Windows Command Prompt:

[image: c_inky]

Linux (Ubuntu) Terminal:

[image: l_inky]

Comment: [190 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/KenacrM46)